# How can I setup Kubernetes in Docker programatically?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I know that in Docker Desktop I can setup "Enable Kubernetes":

[image]

But what I'm looking for is to do that programmatically.
I want (by code) to start a Docker and within it to run some small Kubernetes single-node cluster. The goal is to be able to run some testing code that we can run in CI.
How can this be done?

Comment: You might find Kubernetes-in-a-container setups like [minikube](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/) or [kind](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/) a little easier to manage this way.  You also may find it a little easier to have your CI system provide the Kubernetes setup in some form, rather than having the system under test try to create it itself.

Comment: @DavidMaze ideally I want to be able to run the same docker testing the k8s code locally. which is why I'm looking for a way to setup a docker image that has k8s env in it by using code. As mention this can be done manually via docker desktop I'm looking for the exact same thing just by coding it rather than doing it from the docker desktop UI